# how to get the data of discussion list in spfx using React js with bootstrap i have already create Discussion board list and UI for Discussion Board

Tags: sharepoint-framework

This is my Discussion Borad List and other is my UI of Discussion Borad SO how can i get the data of the List of Discussion borad to UI[image]

Answer (score 0):

A discussion board is just another type of list, meaning you can use either the SharePoint REST API or Graph API to return the list items and display them accordingly.

[Get to know the SharePoint REST service](https://docs.microsoft.com/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/get-to-know-the-sharepoint-rest-service)

[List resource](https://docs.microsoft.com/graph/api/resources/list)